Send e-mail to notify about event in shared google calendar using Apps Script
I am making a google calendar which takes the birth date of employees and calculates their age, so that they have a note in the calendar saying what age they are turning. This updates automatically to the correct age, which is what I want.
However, I also want an e-mail to be sent out to a specific e-mail address one week before anyone turns 30, 40, 50 and 60 (so that they can get them a gift!). This also works well, but only when I input MY e-mail address and when I am the only person who has access to the calendar. When I add another person to the calendar or change the e-mail address, it does not send the e-mail anymore (everything else still works). Do you have any idea how I could fix this?
function uppdateraFodelsedagar() {
 // Defines Excel sheet 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // 
 var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues(); // Gets data (name, birth date, age)
  // Defines the calendar
 var kalender = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('calendar ID'); // 


 // List for all names
 var namnIArket = data.map(function(row) { return row[0]; });


 // List with events to delete
 var händelser = kalender.getEvents(new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), 0, 1), new Date((new Date()).getFullYear() + 10, 11, 31));
  for (var j = 0; j < händelser.length; j++) {
   var händelseNamn = händelser[j].getTitle().split(' fyller ')[0]; // 


   // If the name is not in the sheet, the event is deleted
   if (namnIArket.indexOf(händelseNamn) === -1) {
     händelser[j].deleteEvent(); // 
   }
 }


 // Creates events for X years 
 var antalArFramat = 5; // Events for 5 years are created
  // Loop through every employee
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var namn = data[i][0];
   var fodelsedatum = new Date(data[i][1]);
  
   // Creates events for every person
   for (var ar = (new Date()).getFullYear(); ar < (new Date()).getFullYear() + antalArFramat; ar++) {
     // Calculates age
     var alder = ar - fodelsedatum.getFullYear();
    
     // Calculates birthday
     var fodelsedagDettaAr = new Date(ar, fodelsedatum.getMonth(), fodelsedatum.getDate());
    
     // Name of the event (X turns y!)
     var handelseTitel = namn + ' fyller ' + alder + '!';
    
     // Checks if the event already exists
     var handelser = kalender.getEventsForDay(fodelsedagDettaAr);
     var funnen = false;
    
     for (var k = 0; k < handelser.length; k++) {
       if (handelser[k].getTitle().includes(namn)) {
         // Update if it already exists
         handelser[k].setTitle(handelseTitel);
         funnen = true;
         break;
       }
     }
    
     // If it does not already exist, create it
     if (!funnen) {
       var nyHandelse = kalender.createAllDayEvent(handelseTitel, fodelsedagDettaAr);
      
       // Check if the age is special (20, 30, 40, 50, 60, ...)
       if (alder % 10 === 0) {
         // Create reminder for one week before
         var notisDatum = new Date(fodelsedagDettaAr);
         notisDatum.setDate(notisDatum.getDate() - 6); // 
        
         // Sent e-mail one week before
         var veckaInnanNotis = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('calendar ID').createAllDayEvent(
           'Påminnelse: ' + namn + ' fyller ' + alder + ' år om en vecka!',
           notisDatum
         );
         veckaInnanNotis.addEmailReminder(0); // 

        
         // Specify e-mail
         MailApp.sendEmail("a.b@c.com", "Födelsedagsnotis", "Påminnelse: " + namn + " fyller " + alder + " år om en vecka!");
       }
     }
   }
 }
}

It works perfectly well when I use my own e-mail and when I am the only one with access to the calendar, but not when I add other people

Are you using Installable Triggers to receive an e-mail a week before anyone turns 30, 40, 50 and 60?

Welcome to SO! Have you tried this?

so that they can get them a gift! Hey, any vacancies at this place??
